# Windows 10 - How to keep two folders two way synched

Tags: sync, dropbox, onedrive

I am running Windows 10 and have two folders, one is in my Dropbox folder and the other is in my OneDrive folder that I want to keep two way synched.  Is there a good way to do this in Windows 10?

Some background about why I want to do this: I normally use Dropbox and pay for their service.  I store my Office files on there and can access them on my iPhone and other iOS devices because those iOS apps are integrated with Dropbox.  I have started to use OneNote though and that app is not integrated with Dropbox.  So I am looking for some workaround to access my OneNote files stored in Dropbox through OneNote on iOS's OneDrive integration until the app gets Dropbox integration.

Comment: You could try robocopy with the /mon flag but not sure if you'll get locked files

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get both Dropbox and OneDrive share the same folder. Here are the steps:

1. Open Dropbox Preferences
2. Click on the Account tab
3. Click on the Browse button beside Location and choose the same folder as OneDrive

Now both Dropbox and OneDrive will be using the same folder and files.

Comment: Have you tested this? I'm not disagreeing with you; I'm just concerned that Dropbox's adjustment of last-modified times will play tricks on OneDrive.

Comment: No I haven't used OneDrive at all, but very familiar with Dropbox.  Actually you might be right, the modified dates might cause both services to get confused.  Since you have both, why don't you test it and let us know the results.